# How to cancel the mouseover transition in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is the structure of my HTML

```
svg
   g id=invisibleG
     g
       circle
     g
       circle
     g
       circle
```

So I want something like this on hover of any particular circle

```
svg
       g id=invisibleG
         g
           circle --> radius is increased on hover.....decreased on hoverout
           text
         g
           circle
         g
           circle
```

here is the code

```
 .on("mouseover",function(){
     var r=d3.select(this).attr("r");
     d3.select(this).style('fill','tan')
                    .style('fill-opacity', '1')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("r",50);
     d3.select(this).attr("stroke","blue")
                    .attr("stroke-width",4);

 })

 .on("mouseout",function(){
     var r=d3.select(this).attr("prevRadius");
     d3.select(this).attr("r",r)
                    .attr("stroke-width",0)
                    .style('fill-opacity','0');

 });
```

Now the problem is that when I hover over a circle and immediately hover out of it the transition which is started in mouseover doesn't stop immediately.It completes its transition and the size of radius is increased despite being the fact that mouseout event should be called.And whatever the transition was going should stop.
Please let me know the problem and its solution .

Comment: Where is your mouseout event?

Comment: Added.Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use transitions in both cases. From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions):

> If a newer transition runs on a given element, it implicitly cancels any older transitions, including any that were scheduled but not yet run. This allows new transitions, such as those in response to a new user event, to supersede older transitions even if those older transitions are staged or have staggered delays.

So your code would need to be something like this.

```
.on("mouseover", function() {
    this.prevRadius = d3.select(this).attr("r");
    d3.select(this)
        .style('fill','tan')
        .style('fill-opacity', '1')
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("r",50)
    d3.select(this)
        .attr("stroke","blue")
        .attr("stroke-width",4);

}).on("mouseout", function() {

    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .attr("r", this.prevRadius)
        .attr("stroke-width",0)
        .style('fill-opacity','0');
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/96uN6/).

Answer (score 0):

If your d3 version is mature enough (3.3+), they seemed to have added selection.[**interrupt**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1410)

So you could perhaps try:

```
.on("mouseout",function(){
    d3.select(this).interrupt();
    // if interrupt isn't supported in your version use below
    //d3.select(this).transition().duration(0);
})
```

Otherwise, *newer transitions on the same selection will cancel the old active transitions*. So you could run a new transition on mouseout where you transition to the reset values again. If you want to just freeze the transitions, just run a dummy transition to cancel the old one.

**FURTHER INSIGHTS**

If your goal is to stop the *only* transition of the *r* (radius) dead in its tracks see this [***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/G79fg/) which uses interrupt.

If your goal is to reset the *r* value or the non-transition changes you've made during the mouseover, see this [***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/2G2EC/)

Comment: no it is not happening.Actually initially circle is invisible by fill:opacity 0,then on mouseover I set radius to 50 and opacity to 1.Now When I mouse over ,it start transition to new radius during one second and opacity is get set to 1 immediately.if lets say at .1 second I hoverout of the circle ,then transition to radius 50 should stop (which is not happening).Opacity is getting set to 0 immediately.So overall the circle is opaque to 0 but radius is 50.And when I mouseover again,the circle becomes opaque with radius already set to 50.

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?